# What is correct "Path" usage for startRecordingVideo in distriqt camera ANE?

Tags: camera, distriqt

I'm trying to record a short video using the camera ANE from Distriqt and one of the params for startRecordingVideo() is "path".

I can't figure out what a valid path would be when saving on iOS (and probably Android when I get to it)

Unfortunately the documentation is somewhat lacking...

http://docs.airnativeextensions.com/camera/docs/com/distriqt/extension/camera/Camera.html#startRecordingVideo%28%29

An invalid path stops the device from even starting to record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK that was me just having a stupid 5 min...

var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("sample.mp4");

Camera.instance.startRecordingVideo(file.nativePath);

Comment: Glad you found the solution, basically it's any file.nativePath that's writable for your application. Cheers